# detecting if email is being forward to another email

Tags: email, smtp

Is it possible to determine if the email that I'm sending an email to is being forwarded to another email? Is it possible to get the information about forwarding from the SMTP response or MX records?

Comment: If you mean that you send an email to `joe@example.com`, but Joe forwards it to `lisa@example.com` (or it auto-forwards to `joe.schmo@example.com`), and you want to know about it, then no, that's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In olden times, you could sometimes do this with the SMTP `VRFY` or `EXPN` commands; but this functionality was abused by spammers, and is turned off pretty much everywhere.

For example, with `EXPN` enabled, Sendmail (at the time, something like 8.8) would expose the contents of the `.forward` file if there was one.

Sendmail is no longer the ubiquitous MTA it once used to be, and anyway, many large sites now have public-facing mail servers which don't even know which users are valid, and just accept all inbound email to their domain.  Let alone then that many users would like for this information not to be exposed, neither to spammers nor other curious minds.  And most places, outbound port 25 is blocked these days, except for on dedicated email servers, so you could not connect to port 25 to isssue an `EXPN` even if you wanted to.

Comment: http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html#chat has examples of what it would look like, back in the day.